# How do I grant permission on an Apache 2.4 server?

Tags: apache, wamp

I have an Apache 2.4 server (WAMP) on my pc (running windows 10). It is fine when I connect to it on my pc (the host) but when I test it on another device it simply gives a 403 forbidden error and refuses to load. I have been trying so many solutions online with the config file but to no avail. How do I fix this?

Here is my httpd.conf file: http://pastebin.com/5B5Q31im

Please note that I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a WAMP guy but a linux admin.... and your config file looks like Apache 2.2, 2.4 has some changes where it defines the top level document root directory, and the forbidden error is what usually reminds me I've copied an old config over to a new system...

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
AllowOverride all
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Should be more like

```
DocumentRoot ${INSTALL_DIR}/www
<directory ${INSTALL_DIR}/www>
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</directory>
```